# OpenSSH test: failed proxy connect with privsep

Tags: linux, openssh

I want to measure the coverage of tests of OpenSSH, but I get an error, when I run the connect-privsep test. I can't find out what is the problem.

```
$ ./configure --with-cflags="-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" --with-ldflags="-fprofile-arcs -lgcov"
$ make
$ env TEST_SSH_LOGFILE=/tmp/sshd.log SUDO=sudo make tests LTESTS=connect-privsep
```

**output**:
http://pastebin.com/eDiC894E

**sshd.log**:
http://pastebin.com/sWRCeQiy

The test runs fine without coverage flags:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ env TEST_SSH_LOGFILE=/tmp/sshd.log SUDO=sudo make tests LTESTS=connect-privsep
```

... all tests passed

I installed the following packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

I created the user for privilege separation too:

```
# mkdir /var/empty
# chown root:sys /var/empty
# chmod 755 /var/empty
# groupadd sshd
# useradd -g sshd -c 'sshd privsep' -d /var/empty -s /bin/false sshd
```

I tried it on:

- Ubuntu 14.04 x64 VM
- Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- Debian 8 VM

The results were the - same. (VM=Virtual Machine)

I tried other versions of OpenSSH (6.x) too, but the results were the same.

What should I do?